# Getting blank result while trying to execute a simple while loop in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

This is my PL/SQL WHILE LOOP code below:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
l_check NUMBER;
BEGIN
WHILE (l_check < 5)
LOOP
l_check := l_check + 1;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_check);
END LOOP;
END;
```

When I executed this while loop, it is showing in the message that PL/SQL procedure successfully completed. However, I'm getting a blank result despite using SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't initialised `l_check` so it is NULL the first time it is tested in the WHILE loop. NULL is not less than 5 so the code never enters the loop.

Try to initialize the variable before loop:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
    l_check NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
    WHILE (l_check < 5)
    LOOP
        l_check := l_check + 1;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_check);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: DECLARE
l_check NUMBER := 1;
BEGIN
WHILE (l_check < 5)
LOOP
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_check);
l_check := l_check + 1;
END LOOP;
END;                                                                                                              It worked when I have put DBMS_OUTPUT statement before l_check := l_check + 1;

Comment: @stranger - the important change is ` l_check NUMBER := 1;`. Assigning a value to the variable means it's not null when you test the WHILE condition

Comment: The initial value (0 or 1 or anything else), where you do that (in the DECLARE section or in the execution section), and when you print the current value of `l_check` (before or after incrementing it) will have little effect, other than on exactly which values are printed. They all work the same way. If you want values from 1 to 4, or from 1 to 5, etc., you can adjust the initial value, the placement of the `PUT_LINE` command, and/or the exit condition (`l_check < 5` vs. `<= 5` etc.)